# downgrading the Docker engine version in Colima

Tags: docker, colima

I need help with downgrading the Docker engine version in Colima (https://github.com/abiosoft/colima). Below is the version of my Colima instance/OS:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 23.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="23.10"
VERSION="23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)"
VERSION_CODENAME=mantic
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=mantic
LOGO=ubuntu-logo
```

I have tried to downgrade the Docker engine by using the `colima start --edit` flag, but it seems that downgrading the Docker engine within Colima is not directly supported.

Could you please help me with any possible ways to downgrade the Docker engine in Colima? Thank you.